# PHP if statement error

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

My question is: Why does the script enter ALL if statements? Even if the "in array" question shouldn't let them.

First I show you the array which I am getting back from my model:
In this case the array is just like array([0] => array()) because I only get 1 row back from my DB.

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["Kunden_ID"]=>
    float(250)
    ["Kundentyp_ID"]=>
    float(1)
    ["kundentyp_row_id"]=>
    int(100)
    ["ext_kdnr"]=>
    float(0)
    ["kundentyp_anmerkung"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["status"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "ROLA" // Thats what we are looking for in our statements
  }
}
```

In the following code I need to check whether a specific string is in a specific index of the result array or not.
That way I can create relations which are needed later.

Now to the code:

```
 for($i = 0; $i < $arr_length; $i++){ // for runs only once since we only get 1 row back
        if(in_array("ROLA", $result_array[$i])){ 
// check if you find the string "ROLA" in the array idx $i
            $rola = true;
            $rola_pos = $i;
            $rola_row = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>ROLA TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("ROLA_OBC", $result_array[$i])){
            $rola_obc = true;
            $rola_obc_pos = $i;
            $rola_obc_row = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>ROLA OBC TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("MYTO_FAI", $result_array[$i])){
            $myto_fai = true;
            $myto_fai_pos = $i;
            $myto_fai = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>MYTO FAI TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("OMV", $result_array[$i])){
            $omv = true;
            $omv_pos = $i;
            $omv = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>OMV TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("VAT", $result_array[$i])){
            $vat = true;
            $vat_pos = $i;
            $vat = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>VAT TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("PLAKETTEN", $result_array[$i])){
            $plaketten = true;
            $plaketten_pos = $i;
            $plaketten = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>PLAKETTEN TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("SPEDITION", $result_array[$i])){
            $spedition = true;
            $spedition_pos = $i;
            $spedition = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>SPEDITION TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("MOEST", $result_array[$i])){
            $moest = true;
            $moest_pos = $i;
            $moest = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>MOEST TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("BERUFUNGEN", $result_array[$i])){
            $berufungen = true;
            $berufungen_pos = $i;
            $berufungen = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>BERUFUNGEN TYP AKTIV";
        }
        if(in_array("DIVERSE", $result_array[$i])){
            $diverse = true;
            $diverse_pos = $i;
            $diverse = $result_array[$i]["kundentyp_row_id"];
            echo "<br/>DIVERSE TYP AKTIV";
        }
    }
```

As you see the result array contains the string "ROLA" therefore the first IF statement should be true and executed. Which is the case.
BUT all other if statements appear to be true as well.
Why?

**EDIT**

As requested here is something you can copy paste into a php file to reproduce it :

```
    $testArr = array ( 0 => array ( 'Kunden_ID' => 250, 'Kundentyp_ID' => 1, 'kundentyp_row_id' => 100, 'ext_kdnr' => 0, 'kundentyp_anmerkung' => '', 'status' => '', 'name' => 'ROLA', ));

$length = count($testArr);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ){
    if(in_array("ROLA", $testArr[$i])){
        $rola = true;
        echo "<br/>ROLA TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("ROLA_OBC", $testArr[$i])){
        $rola_obc = true;
        echo "<br/>ROLA OBC TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("MYTO_FAI", $testArr[$i])){
        $myto_fai = true;
        echo "<br/>MYTO FAI TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("OMV", $testArr[$i])){
        $omv = true;
        echo "<br/>OMV TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("VAT", $testArr[$i])){
        $vat = true;
        echo "<br/>VAT TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("PLAKETTEN", $testArr[$i])){
        $plaketten = true;
        echo "<br/>PLAKETTEN TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("SPEDITION", $testArr[$i])){
        $spedition = true;
        echo "<br/>SPEDITION TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("MOEST", $testArr[$i])){
        $moest = true;
        echo "<br/>MOEST TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("BERUFUNGEN", $testArr[$i])){
        $berufungen = true;
        echo "<br/>BERUFUNGEN TYP AKTIV";
    }
    if(in_array("DIVERSE", $testArr[$i])){
        $diverse = true;
        echo "<br/>DIVERSE TYP AKTIV";
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want to use `in_array("whatever", $result_array)`, not `$result_array[$i]`...

Comment: Not related to your bug but you should **defiantly use a `loop`**, this code has so many repetitions that it just screams it :)

Comment: @EdCottrell I don't want to check if its in the WHOLE array. I need to see if its in the particular subarray. Because if I get into the result_array[1] for example then I know that all other entries are related to the STRING im looking for. If i simply check if its in the whole array I cant really make any specific relations

Comment: @noa-dev well, that's not clear from your question. You have posted a of of code, but much of it is irrelevant or redundant. Try simplifying and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @EdCottrell Thanks for your feedback. I have removed the irrelevant parts

Comment: @noa-dev I can't reproduce your error. Try to `var_export` $result array before the loop and make a script, that everybody can run and reproduce the bug. PS: I don't believe, that in_array function is working incorrectly.

Comment: @frz3993 It is a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: @user4035 I have edited my question and added code to copy for a reproduction below

Comment: **Notice:** I believe I know what's the problem: Are you aware that you overwrite the variables? I mean,it's a loop and you don't save the values of the variables so you'll find yourself ending with the boolean values of the last item in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use "strict" flag (third parameter of in_array).
For example:

```
if(in_array("ROLA", $testArr[$i], true)){
    $rola = true;
    echo "<br/>ROLA TYP AKTIV";
}
if(in_array("ROLA_OBC", $testArr[$i], true)){
    $rola_obc = true;
    echo "<br/>ROLA OBC TYP AKTIV";
}
if(in_array("MYTO_FAI", $testArr[$i], true)){
    $myto_fai = true;
    echo "<br/>MYTO FAI TYP AKTIV";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your array is an associative array, not just a normal array

Please take a look at the manual page 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Apparently `in_array()` goes crazy with associative array

You may want to extract values and use `in_array()` on values array only